# Change the scale factor in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change the scaling factor of a UIScrollView? What I mean is I can only use two pinch gesture to completely zoom-out the content view to its minimum scale or two expand gesture to completely zoom-in the content view to its maximum value. Like for example, the minimum scale of the UIScrollView is 0.32 and just by two pinch gesture the content view will scaled to 0.32.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property directly for that, but I bet you could make it work by implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and overriding the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method, then from that method manually alter the `UIScrollView`'s `zoomScale` property.

Comment: I see, I know what you mean. Then from the override viewForZoomingInScrollView: method I will call its parent method? Thanks